# Replacing time-average for fast-varying function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, average

Consider the second order differential equation as follows
$$ \frac{d^2 f(t)}{dt^2} = \alpha(t) f(t), $$

where the variable $t$ is time. A result very often used in Physics is that, if $\alpha(t)$ varies in time much faster than $f(t)$, one can replace it by its average in time

$$ \frac{d^2 f(t)}{dt^2} \approx \overline{\alpha(t)} f(t), $$

where

$$ \overline{\alpha(t)} = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \alpha(t) dt.$$

This result sounds very intuitive to me, but I can't seem to prove it. Can I have a hint or a reference for this?

Comment: What exactly do you intend to prove?

Comment: Hi Sammy. I'm intending to prove that, under the assumption that $\alpha(t)$ is a function that varies in $t$ much faster than $f(t)$, the approximation in my second equation is valid.

Comment: What do you mean by valid?

Comment: Hi Ninad. By valid I mean that the second equation in my question is true when $\alpha(t)$ is a function that varies in time much faster than $f(t)$. I suppose another way to express this is if $f$ and $\alpha$ are periodic functions in $t$ with frequencies $\omega_f$ and $\omega_{\alpha}$, respectively, where $\omega_{\alpha} \gg \omega_f$, then an approximate solution for $f(t)$ can be found by solving the second equation, where $\alpha(t)$ is replaced by its time-average as defined in the question. However, this result is used for functions that are not necessarily periodic in $t$.

Comment: Where exactly have you seen this?

Comment: @Sal I have seen it in simplifying the set of Mathieu's equations that appear in the context of the motion of ions in a Paul trap. A differential equation of the type $u''(t)= A\cos^2(\Omega t) u(t)$ can be approximated by $u''(t) \approx (A/2) u(t)$. Chapter 13 of M. Nakahara's "Quantum Computing: from Linear Algebra to Physical Realizations" makes use of this result.